# Avoid deserializing a JSON string token to a numeric property

Tags: c#, json, string, json.net, deserialization

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "x": "50"
}
```

And the class looks like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public float? x { get; set; }
}
```

And when using

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json);
```

No exception is thrown, JSON.NET just converts the string value "50" into a float value 50.0.

This question is raised in the the context of input-validation. I want to get an exception, because the JSON string does not comply to the contract (the `x` field should be a real float).

And I don't want to use property annotations in the 'Test' class.

Is there a JsonSerializerSettings which can be be used to avoid this?

Comment: you can mark the propery with `[JsonIgnore]` attribute

Comment: What _do_ you want to happen?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic - I may be wrong, but I think OP wants to ignore it *because* it's in quotes. If so, OP, this surely is a mismatch between the serialized output and the consumer's expectations? Isn't this more of a design consideration?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the OP's expectations really are at the moment, as they haven't been put in the question...

Comment: "x": "50" <<< "50" is a string, rather than 50 which would be a numeric. OP wants "50" to fail because it's not a numeric.

Comment: @AndyJ - I'd have guessed the same, but until OP confirms I'm not answering.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ Yep, and as others pointed out the OP hasn't said what the desired outcome should actually be.

Comment: where's agatha christie when you need her

Comment: Well they do say _No exception is thrown_, which does seem to indicate a desire for this to throw an exception.

Comment: potentially using getter and setters would allow the value to be examined for its primitive type and then a process run thereafter. that said, potentially the jsonconvert will have already munged things by then (in fact, i think it all happens via reflection -doh!)

Comment: Your latest edit introduces an all new question altogether.

Comment: @CodeCaster ; I've removed second question, sorry for disturbances...

Comment: No problem. I think schema validation can detect this, but it's something you'll have to research separately from this approach (throwing during deserialization). Feel free to ask a question if you can't find anything about it. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON.NET liberally parses numbers-in-strings (`"50"`) as numbers. There's no trivial way to turn this off, as far as I can find.

You could create a custom converter that disallows this:

```
public class NumberConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly Type[] _typesNotToReadAsString = { typeof(float), typeof(float?) };

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return _typesNotToReadAsString.Any(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(objectType));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);

        if (_typesNotToReadAsString.Contains(objectType) && token.Type == JTokenType.String)
        {
            string exceptionString = string.Format("Won't convert string to type {0}", objectType.FullName);
            throw new JsonSerializationException(exceptionString);
        }

        return token.ToObject(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

The converter reports to be able to deserialize into specified types, in this case `float` and `float?`, but configurable.

Upon deserialization, it inspects the token type. Some token types for given JSON input:

- `"50"`: `JTokenType.String`
- `50`: `JTokenType.Integer`
- `42.1415`: `JTokenType.Float`

This way the converter can determine whether the current token is formatted as desired. When the token type is a string, the above converter will throw an exception stating it won't convert a string to the desired type.

When the token type is anything else, the converter will convert the token to the appropriate numeric type through `token.ToObject(objectType)`. That method will also handle non-numeric input by throwing the appropriate exception, for example *"Can not convert Array to Single."*.

Given a class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public float Bar { get; set; }
    public string Baz { get; set; }
    public float? Qux { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize a JSON string using above converter, this will work:

```
var jsonString = "{ \"Bar\" : 50, \"Baz\" : \"zaB\", \"Qux\" : 42.1415 }";
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(jsonString, new NumberConverter());
```

While this will throw:

```
var jsonString = "{ \"Bar\" : 50, \"Baz\" : \"zaB\", \"Qux\" : \"42.1415\" }";
var foo2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(jsonString, new NumberConverter());
```